# Is $\int_a^{b}f(x) dx = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty } \int_a^{b_k}f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be integrable.

Let $b_k \subset [a,b]$ be a sequence such that $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} {b_k} = b$

Consider the integral $\int_a^{b}f(x) dx$.
Is it always the case that $$\int_a^{b}f(x) dx = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty } \int_a^{b_k}f(x)?$$

If yes, why? If no, could you please provide a counterexample?

I feel that is the case, however, not sure how to prove it(or at least start my proof)

Comment: Reimann integrable, Lebesgue integrable, or something else?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are dealing with the Riemann integral. First recall that if $f$ is integrable on a closed interval $[a,b]$, then $f$ has to be bounded. Take $M=\sup_{x\in[a,b]} |f(x)|$,then

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\int_{b_k}^b f(x)dx\right|\leq\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{b_k}^b Mdx=\lim_{k\to\infty}M(b-b_k)=0$$
Thus the result follows.

Comment: Your "bounded" conclusion is true only for Reimann integrable, not all definitions of integrable.

Answer (score 1):

The above theorem is true. The integrability condition of the function and limit at posinfinity on sequence $b_k$ assures you that your both integrals are equal.

Comment: thank you. Is it indeed a theorem? or just a statement

Comment: It can be a theorem under these two conditions mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Using additivity property of definite integrals, **if** we can write 
 $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^{b_1}f(x)dx +\int_{b_1}^{b_2}f(x)dx+ \int_{b_2}^{b_3}f(x)dx +...+\int_{b_k}^{b_{k+1}}f(x)dx +... $
$= a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + ... + a_{k+1}+... $ 
 $=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i$.
 Now, the other expression $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty } \int_a^{b_k}f(x)$ is nothing but the limit partial sums.
 But there is something I'm not sure of which is if the use of additivity property in the first step is valid  or not . Other than that this offers an intuitive explaination for why the statement must be true. Comments are welcome.